# How do I get to $4uu^T$ from $4uu^{T}uu^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

In proving that a Householder matrix $I-2uu^T$ is orthogonal (with $||u||_2 = 1$), I've run into the equality through FOILing $PP^T = I-4uu^T+4uu^Tuu^T$. How do I make the second and third terms equal? Does the $u^Tu$ disappear?

Comment: Is $u$ a unit vector? If so then $u^Tu=1$

Comment: Don't forget that matrix multiplication is associative!

Comment: Yeah it is, is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes it is sufficient. $uu^Tuu^T = u(u^Tu)u^T = u\,1\,u^T = uu^T$